# Open modal when an API containing specific data is called from a specific website in PHP (iTop) for a specific user session

Tags: php, events, websocket

## Problem

I need to open a modal in my [iTop](https://www.combodo.com/itop-193) page UI.php ( and possibly only on a specific user session) when an api is called from [3cx](https://www.3cx.com/) (a popular softphone solution)  to my [iTop](https://www.combodo.com/itop-193) server (A popular FOSS Ticketing/ Helpdesk solution)

## Environment

PHP : 7.4.3 
OS : Ubuntu 20.04 
iTop version : 2.7

## What I have tried

1. SSE (Server side events) in PHP. SSE takes too much memory?* and I cannot seem to make it work.
2. Changing the api to store the api output in a file that can be destructured to check if the api call was from 3cx. Cannot implement as I would I have reload the page to show the modal.

## Things I didn't try

1. Mysql Triggers. (I tried to store it in a database which can trigger a sql event which in turn would open the modal using javascript/AJAX)
2. Websockets (too complex)

## Shortcomings

As PHP is static and the event can be triggered anytime with no info about it, It is difficult to achieve this behaviour without reloading the page.

Comment: Is this your API? Do you have access to just add the information to the json so you can check for it

Comment: You can either use ajax with regular polling or websockets with server push, but may be simpker if you use an existing event bridge or message queue as opposed to creating your own.

Comment: Yes it is my api ( I'll update the question if It is required)

Comment: @Shadow how Would I use a messaging to open  a modal ?

Comment: The event bridge or message queue sends the notification to the appropriate session, which is retrieved / detected by javascript in the browser and js can display the modal.

Comment: would that all work on client side after an api has called or would it work server side ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what your question is about.

Comment: @Shadow I wanted to say as php does not refresh the page , so I would still need to use ajax/js to use the message queue /event bridge right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252739/discussion-between-lucifer-and-shadow).

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing extension from Combodo that does exactly what you are looking for, it's called [Computer Telephony Integration](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=extensions:combodo-telephony-integration).

Basically

- Inbound phone calls received by a support agent may be transformed into an iTop WEB page on the agent's own browser: a dashboard containing information on the caller(s) and his(their) ongoing tickets is displayed and the creation of new tickets can be directly launched from there,
- Outbound phone calls may be initiated with the caller of a given ticket, directly from the ticket's detailed display,
  New Phone Call object tracks the phone calls that occurred and that led to a ticket modification,
- Behaviour of the extension is highly configurable to fit phone system capabilities and to best answer support teams' requirements.

And [here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85bUq0K5t0Q&ab_channel=iTopbyCombodo) of a webinar made by Combodo about that extension.

Comment: yes , but its paid and not even close to budget for something that we already have done but requires polish.

Thanks for your answer but we already implemented a code that would trigger a modal  through mysql triggers